Problem solving geodesic equations numerically
I been having trouble solving the geodesic equations. The end goal is to plot them on a surface. I firstly calculated the Christoffel symbols and then inserted the differential equation in an ODE solver, I't worked util the metric became to complex, now I am struggling to find a numerical algoritm I could use, any help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone :)

Computational Science might be more appropriate for this question.

I't worked util the metric became to complex. It’s not clear what that means.

If you're trying to avoid computing Christoffel symbols, you might find it helpful to use the variational formulation of the geodesic equation:
\begin{align*}
\delta \int_0^\alpha du \frac{dx^\mu}{du} \frac{dx^\nu}{du} g_{\mu\nu}(x(u)) = 0,\quad x(0)=x_0,\quad x(\alpha)=x_\alpha
\end{align*}
Note that this is formally equivalent to minimizing
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\alpha du\sqrt{\frac{dx^\mu}{du} \frac{dx^\nu}{du} g_{\mu\nu}(x(u))}
\end{align*}
(heuristically, an elastic string stretched between two points takes the path of shortest length.)
You can then directly minimize the length integral using, e.g., a hybrid numerical algorithm.
